# Prevent people from using levers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a battlefield and want to include an area for "admins" and the like to enter and leave a certain area without others being able to do the same thing. I don't want to use commands such as teleporting, as it will be too jarring to see, and I want it to be a legitimate door.

Is there a way to prevent someone from using a lever? For example, if someone had a certain tag or item on them, they are unable to right-click the lever. I'm on 1.17.1.

Comment: You can prevent the redstone circuit from executing with a command block attached to the lever. I can’t write up a full answer currently, but I *think* all you need is a command block, redstone dust and torch along with a comparator. Since the lever activates redstone you can use it to power the command block and have the command block complete the circuit if it detects the tag.

Comment: That would work, provided that I wasn't attempting to put the lever right next to the door lol. I wouldn't be able to do that since it would power the door anyway.

Comment: You could add a one block buffer between the lever and door to prevent it from opening; but, it doesn’t sound like you want to do that. I’m not sure if it can be accomplished with scoreboard or not, but who knows. ‍♀️

Comment: I might try to form an actual answer another day, but for anyone who may try or even the op, make a scoreboard with the criteria [use.lever] and and two command block under the door, one that will check if it is open + someone with a tag+score, if so, open and another that is reverse. Make sure the lever isn't conected to the door.

Comment: So, i just found out that the used criteria is for placed blocks, not when you act on them (so not when you press the lever, but rather, when you place the block lever). Would it be enough to open the door if the corret player is close enough?

Comment: I could definitely just say "screw it" and utilize commands to open it wirelessly, but I was somewhat hoping for the ability to use a lever with as little command block usage as possible (specifically because most of the time the command block wouldn't be hidden in the build I have).

Comment: Well, acording to (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349338/scoreboard-for-who-flips-a-lever), you really can't detect who flipped it. You can't do it with redstone, so i can't see a propper solution to it. How come you say you can't hide the command block on your building? You need a two block spaces under the door's block like this [https://prnt.sc/1n2qadn]

Comment: Per hiding the command block, I'm attempting to do your [standard lever-door setup](http://prnt.sc/1n2r4w6). The problem with using a command block is no matter what orientation I put the command block, [it will always](http://prnt.sc/1n2s94z) [trigger the door to open,](http://prnt.sc/1n2sonr) [and can cause the command block to be seen](http://prnt.sc/1n2t16y) (which I don't want).

Comment: But why does the lever has to be super close to the door, rather then 1 block away or diagonally? Also, if you are gonna use a command block, you don't even need the lever. [https://prnt.sc/1n2xxhi] A solution to your lever positioning problem (just use a non-conductor block like stairs, glasses...) and under it, the solution i'd propose with no lever. Or diagonally [https://prnt.sc/1n315t4]

Answer (score 1):

So I made a slightly different solution for you using a sign.

Using this command to give a player a custom sign that places a Redstone torch underneath the door if the player clicking the sign has the `admin` tag:

```
/give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:'{"text":"Click to open"}',Text2:'{"text":"door","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"execute if entity @s[tag=admin] run setblock -63 54 -7 redstone_torch"}}'}} 1
```

At the end of the command, you can change the position, x y z values, to wherever your door is placed, to place a Redstone torch underneath the door.

This completely hides the opening mechanism underground. And using a few repeaters and a command block to replace the touch with air to close the door.
`setblock -63 54 -7 air`

I also used an Observer to detect the torch so if someone with admin tag spam clicked the sign the door would not stay open. Like this:
[image: Door open]

---

I also placed this command in a repeating command block to teleport any player without the admin tag away from the door:

```
execute as @a[x=-63,y=56,z=-7,distance=..1] at @s unless entity @s[tag=admin] run tp @s ~0.3 ~ ~
```

I found that 0.3 was a good amount, at 0.2 you can sprint thru it. And make sure the y position is at feet level, `y=56` if it's at the head level it doesn't affect any player walking thru the door.

I also made a quick demonstration video: